# JQuery 'Object' is undefined when reference Jquery twice

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a asp.net page, in its header section I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
```

And I also have:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
    <iframe src="frameDemo.aspx" scrolling="no" style="border:0px" width="500"></iframe>
</div>
```

And in the frameDemo.aspx header section, I also have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Every time I press the debug button, it open up IE and gives me an error which says:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Object' is undefined

I press continue, and it pops up again and again about 5 to 6 times for the same error message. And then finally it shows the page and is working fine.

But if I copy the URL and open it in another browser, it doesn't show any error message. Or if I set Safari/Firefox as a debugging browser, the error message doesn't show up either. It looks like only using IE as the debugging browser will produce the error.

Also, if I remove the following from frameDemo.aspx page, the error doesn't show up as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
```

So it looks like if I reference the JQuery twice in a sub-iframe page, and debug in IE browser I will get that error message.

Has anyone come across this issue? Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe i dont undertstand your question, but why would you want to reference jquery twice in the first place?

Comment: Yes it does give an error when you refer or user the same file twice in your page....

Comment: i didn't want to reference twice, I just reference in two different aspx page, but one of the page include another page into its iFrame tag. so it sort of being reference twice but not.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over the other instance of jQuery then consider using

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/